# strapi - restrict user to fetch only data related to him

Tags: koa, strapi

Usually, a logged-in user gets all entries of a Content Type.

I created a "snippets" content type `(_id,name,content,users<<->>snippets)`

`<<->>` means "has and belongs to many" relation.

I created some test users and make a request:

`curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ...'  http://localhost:1337/snippets/`

Main Problem: an authenticated user should only see the entries assigned to him. Instead, a logged-in user gets all snippets, which is bad.

How is it possible to modify the `fetchAll(ctx.query);` query to take that into account so it does something like `fetchAll(ctx.state.user.id);` at the `/`-route->`find`-method ?

The basic find method is here:

```
find: async (ctx) => {

    if (ctx.query._q) {
      return strapi.services.snippet.search(ctx.query);
    } else {
      return strapi.services.snippet.fetchAll(ctx.query);
    }
},
```

Sub-Question: Does strapi even know which user is logged in when I do Bearer-Token Authentication ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could set up a /snippets/me route under the snippets config.

That route could call the Snippets.me controller method which would check for the user then query snippets based on the user.

So in `api/snippet/config/routes.json` there would be something like :

```
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/snippets/me",
      "handler": "Snippets.me",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    },
```

Then in the controller (`api/snippet/controllers/Snippet.js`), you could do something like:

```
  me: async (ctx) => {
    const user = ctx.state.user;    
    if (!user) {
      return ctx.badRequest(null, [{ messages: [{ id: 'No authorization header was found' }] }]);
    }

    const data = await strapi.services.snippet.fetch({user:user.id});  

    if(!data){
      return ctx.notFound();
    }

    ctx.send(data);
  },
```

Then you would give authenticated users permissions for the me route not for the overall snippets route.

Comment: I see that this is the first/only answer you gave and I wanted to explicitly thank you for being so kind to register to help me! :-)

Comment: I get only one snippet. does fetch({user:user.id});  fetch only one entry? fetchAll({user:user.id}) does not give any output

Comment: are the ?_sort/find querys still possible with that solution?

Comment: can the query of ctx.query be extended to restrict to the user:user.id part? so I could use the /-route find model

Comment: The query construction might be off using fetchAll().  If there is more than one snippet per user, that should work. Play around with it. _sort and other params should work, you just have to construct the query including those properties.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking in the last question, but the reason I suggested this method is because the user object exists on the backend.  AFAIK, you don't know the user id until you get server side. To use the /route (which I think you're suggesting maybe /route/:id?) method you would have to already know which user was authenticated, which means that data was coming from the front end, which means your user object is on the front end, which is a bad idea, it contains all your password info.

Comment: the user is only stored in the strapi backend. Frontend is not existing yet. Before I can do a query (I simulate that via curl or insomnia), I have to authenticate, so I get a Bearer token, and with this Bearer token I can make a query. At this moment strapi should know who I am because I've sent my token along with my query. And I really mean the main route, in my case "path": "/snippets" - which uses the "find" module.export. so, instead return strapi.services.snippet.fetchAll(ctx.query); I need something which extends the ctx.query with my {user:user.id}, I guess

Comment: Unfortunately it returns an item not belonging to the logged-in user. Does strapi even know which user is logged in when I do Bearer-Token Authentication ? Or is this token authentication actually just a legitimation ? then it should not be called authentication

Comment: ctx.state.user should be the logged in user object.  If the snippets have a relation to the users, you should be able to find associated snippets by the user id.  Without seeing your code and your project, I can't really speak to any more specifics.

Comment: I can only advise you to look through the strapi documentation for filters.  if the snippets content types have a user as a property, you should be able to construct a query object using that user as a filter and send that with fetchAll.

Comment: That would work, thanks!. However, what about GraphQL plugin? It won't get affected as Controller is web api-specific, isn't it? There should be more data-oriented solution and not api-access-point-specific implementation. Just thinking aloud...

Comment: `.fetch` has now to be replaced by `.find`

Answer (score 4):

The above is correct, except with newer versions of strapi. Use `find` and not `fetch` :)

```
const data = await strapi.services.snippet.find({ user: user.id });
```

Strapi v3.0.0-beta.20

Comment: Where does the snippet service come from? I'm getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined"

Comment: It will be available in the controller file If you follow the right controller structure. Or use the strapi CLI to generate the controller.

Comment: Ooh this is a separate object. IS there any way to do this for user objects? /users/me is only for get requests.

Answer (score 4):

A possibility would be to extend the query used by `find` and `findOne` in the controllers with a restriction regarding the logged in user. In this case you might also want to adapt the `count` endpoint to be consistent.

This would result in:

```
withOwnerQuery: (ctx, ownerPath) => {
  const user = ctx.state.user;
  if (!user) {
    ctx.badRequest(null, [
      { messages: [{ id: "No authorization header was found" }] },
    ]);
    return null;
  }
  return { ...ctx.query, [ownerPath]: user.id };
};

find: async (ctx) => {
    ctx.query = withOwnerQuery(ctx, "owner.id");
    if (ctx.query._q) {
      return strapi.services.snippet.search(ctx.query);
    } else {
      return strapi.services.snippet.fetchAll(ctx.query);
    }
},

// analogous for for findOne
```

Depending on your usage of controllers and services you could achieve the same thing via adapting the [service methods](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/services.html#core-services).

This kind of solution would work with the GraphQL plugin.