# How to add custom route for user

Tags: strapi

I have created a `books` content type containg books. Each book in the collection belongs to a user (user content type provided by Strapi).

I want to return list of books owned by authenticated user at `/users/me/books` endpoint. Where can I add this route and handler as there is `/api/books` directory containing books related route, controllers, etc. but not `/api/users` directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend or override using the extensions system.

```
extensions/users-permissions/controllers
```

Just add the controller you want to extend or override as a .js file like so:

So to override the `me` endpoint under `User.js` you only need to define the method again:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  //Override me
  async me(ctx) {
      //do your thing
  }
};
```

To extend, not override, means to add another endpoint, therefor you need to define it, add a route and set permissions for it. The routes.js files should be created at:

```
extensions/users-permissions/config/routes.json
```

Like so:

```
{
    "routes": [
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/users/me/books",
      "handler": "User.getUserBooks",
      "config": {
        "policies": [],
        "prefix": "",
        "description": "description",
        "tag": {
          "plugin": "users-permissions",
          "name": "User",
          "actionType": "find"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

The controller this time (same location as in beginning):

```
module.exports = {
    async getUserBooks(ctx) {
      //add logic
    }
}
```

OP correctly added:

> After adding custom route and controller, one has to go to Admin Panel(log in as admin)>Roles and Permission> Users-Permission. There you can find the newly added route and have to enable it by checking it.

The originals(if you need examples) are located at:

```
/node_modules/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/config/routes.json
/node_modules/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/controllers/User.js
```

**I don't think you should extend the User controller as it isn't logically correct**. You are trying to GET books - you should extend the book api in the same way.
From what I can tell a `ContentType` doesn't contain information about its creator(you're welcome to educate me if it's not true).
So to tackle that you can add to your `ContentType` "books" a relation to `User`.
Then I think you should extend the books api with a endpoint that returns books "belonging" to that user using the `ctx` received.

Also - [check this question out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265503/strapi-restrict-user-to-fetch-only-data-related-to-him)

Comment if you need more info.

Comment: Can you provide where exactly to add controller. I am new to Strapi.

Comment: I have overrided the users/me route. How do I define users/me/books route? and in which file?

Comment: I did what you asked. Now I am getting 403 error instead of 404 even though i have attached jwt token of logged in user in postman to the request. I have not yet added logic to retrieve books yet, just trying to return dummy object from the route.

Comment: Related to your opinion that I should add a books route instead of user; wouldn't it be more appropriate to add a user route like i am trying to do? Like /users/me/books should return logged in users books. I already have user relation in books ContentType with many to one relationship (one user has many books).

Comment: ans comment #1: OK 403 even though it's a permissions issue, it means that it found your endpoint. How to authenticate is a totally different question so I advise you to test in development environment with public permissions allowed, just to separate the 2 things you are trying to do(query & authenticate).
ans comment #2: It's my opinion because you are querying books(and not users). You can do what you think is best for you.

Comment: I found out why it was giving 403 error. After adding custom route and controller, one has to go to Admin Panel(log in as admin)>Roles and Permission> Users-Permission. There you can find the newly added route and have to enable it by checking it. Then you get whatever you from route when you access it.

Comment: Thanks Gosh!! You saved my day! I was looking to add an api /users/bla but always ended up with /user-permissions/bla...until I read your answer en found config: prefix: "" in routes. Awesome

Comment: @jr00n happy to help