# Why doesn't strapi's `find()` query return an array?

Tags: javascript, koa, strapi

### Context

I have a front end app that requires an array of blog posts from the API, and when you call `http://strapi-url/posts/` with a GET request, it returns all the results as objects in an array. **Happy days.**

### Problem

Eventually I want to have more complex GET options with query params, so I need to modify the post controller and write a custom function for `find()`.

When I modify the `find()` function in `api/post/controllers/post.js` , and just make it return the result of `strapi.query('post').find()`, it returns an object with keys rather than an array.

### Code

```js
 async find(ctx) {
    let entity = await.strapi.query('post').find();
    return sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.post });
  },
```

I know I could simply convert it into an array in the front end, but feels like a messy solution, and I would rather understand *why* it doesn't return an array, and what would be the best way to approach a solution.

Comment: how many sets of objects does it return ? if it returns multiple objects, then it's an array that's being returned.

Comment: No, as I mentioned, it is an object with keys i.e
{
  0: { data: 1 },
  1: { data: 2}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in sanitizeEntity actually does this. You can check it out in the source code(`node_modules/strapi-utils/lib/sanitize-entity.js`). Also you can see this by dropping the sanitizeEntity row - you will get an array from `await.strapi.query('post').find()`.

You can run the following test ([add a custom endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62633311/how-to-add-custom-route-for-user/62634233#62634233)) to see the results:

```
  async test2(ctx) {
    let entity = await strapi.query('post').find();
    ctx.send({
      message: 'okay',
      posts: entity,
      sanitizedPosts: sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.post })
    }, 200);
  }
```

You can solve it by making your own **custom sanitize function** which returns an array OR by processing the result before returning it like so:

```
let entity = await strapi.query('post').find();
let sanitizedEntity = sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.post });
//process sanitized results to an array 
//return the result as array
```